# Element not clickable in the next page by selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I try to scrape all the pages of a URL by selenium python, but only could get the values from the 1st page. The code is going to the next page but same code is not working to scrape ending with an error. The error is " Element ... is not clickable at point (208, 17). Other element would receive the click: ...". Here is the code

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as W
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as E


def page_scrape():
    driver.maximize_window()
    ADDRESS_LOCATIONS_TEASER = '//div[contains(@class,"all-stores accordian ng-star-inserted")]'
    ADDRESS_LOCATIONS = './/div[contains(@class,"accordian-header")]'
    teaser = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ADDRESS_LOCATIONS_TEASER)
    locations = teaser.find_elements(By.XPATH, ADDRESS_LOCATIONS)

    for loc in locations:
        add = loc.find_element(By.XPATH, './/a[@href]').click()
        add1 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//address[contains(@class, 'address-block')]").text
        print(add1)
        Services_Types_TEASER = '//div[contains(@class, "store-accordian store-accordian-flex ng-star-inserted")]'
        Service_Types = './/div[contains(@class, "store-dine-flx ng-star-inserted")]'
        services_teaser = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, Services_Types_TEASER)
        services_list = services_teaser.find_elements(By.XPATH, Service_Types)

        types_of_services = '//div[contains(@id,"divrestaurant2")]'
        types_of_services_teaser = './/div[contains(@class,"services ng-star-inserted")]'
        types_of_services_find = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, types_of_services)
        types_of_service_list = types_of_services_find.find_elements(By.XPATH, types_of_services_teaser)
        text = []
        for types in types_of_service_list:
            if types.text == 'Services in diesem Restaurant':
                text = "'{}':".format(types.text)
            elif types.text == 'Betreiber':
                exit
            else:
                text = "{0},'{1}'".format(text, types.text)

        print(text)
        for services_types in services_list:
            # service = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/h5').text
            print(services_types.text)



driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/doyel/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.kfc.de/find-a-kfc')

results = pd.DataFrame(columns=['address', 'PLZ', 'Telephone' 'Restaurant Services'])


COOKIE_PATH = '//button[contains(@id,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler")]'
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,COOKIE_PATH).click()
flag = True
while True:
    page_scrape()
    next_page = '//a[@aria-label="Next page"]'
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, next_page).click()
        print("next page")
        time.sleep(2)

    except:
        print("last page reached")
        break










#//p[@class='mb-2']//font//font[contains(text(),'Schnellerstr.')]

#print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not trivial, it's doable, and here is one way to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
import time as t 
from tqdm import tqdm ## if using Jupyter notebook, import as from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

restaurant_list = []
driver.get('https://www.kfc.de/find-a-kfc')

try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-reject-all-handler"))).click()
    print('dismissed cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
header = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.TAG_NAME, "app-common-header")))
driver.execute_script("""
var element = arguments[0];
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
""", header)
for x in tqdm(range(1, 21)):
    kfc_rests = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="all-stores accordian ng-star-inserted"]//app-accordian[@class="card carryout-address ng-star-inserted"]')))
    for k in kfc_rests:
        k.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        k.click()
        name = k.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'strong').text
        address = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//address[@class="address-block"]/p'))).text.replace('\n', ' ').strip()
        try:
            services = ', '.join([x.text.strip() for x in wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="services ng-star-inserted"]//li')))])
        except Exception as e:
            services = 'Not specified'
        restaurant_list.append((name, address, services))
    try:
        next_page = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//li[@class="pagination-next ng-star-inserted"]//a[@aria-label="Next page"]')))
        next_page.location_once_scrolled_into_view
        next_page.click()
    except Exception as e:
        print('end of list')
        break
df = pd.DataFrame(restaurant_list, columns = ['Name', 'Address', 'Services'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
dismissed cookies
95%
19/20 [01:41<00:05, 5.91s/it]
end of list
Name    Address Services
0   KFC BERLIN  Grenzallee 37 12057 Berlin  Lieferung, Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung, Click & Collect
1   KFC BERLIN  Gatower Straße 56 13595 Berlin  Lieferung, Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung, Click & Collect
2   KFC BERLIN  Mall of Berlin Leipziger Platz 12 10117 Berlin  Lieferung, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung, Click & Collect
3   KFC BERLIN  Klosterstraße 3 13581 Berlin    Lieferung, EC-Zahlung, Click & Collect
4   KFC BERLIN  Schnellerstr. 18a 12439 Berlin  Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung, Click & Collect
... ... ... ...
191 KFC SAARBRÜCKEN Wolfseck 6 66130 Saarbrücken    Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung
192 KFC SAARLOUIS   Provinzialstr. 246 66740 Saarlouis  Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung
193 KFC OFFENBURG   Heinrich-Hertz-Str. 3 77656 Offenburg   Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung
194 KFC FREIBURG    Tullastraße 68 79108 Freiburg   Lieferung, Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung
195 KFC FRANKFURT FLUGHAFEN Tullastraße 68 79108 Freiburg   Lieferung, Drive Thru, Free Refill, EC-Zahlung
196 rows × 3 columns
```

Selenium documentation can be found at: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Pandas documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

And for TQDM, go to https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

Answer (score 0):

The simple (VBA) solution I use which seems to work in all cases (please adjust the code to Python):

```
driver.ExecuteScript "arguments[0].click();", driver.FindElementByXPath("//div[@id='search-engine']/div/div/div[2]")
```

Of course, you can use findelementbywhatever...